# Magento 2: How to move product attribute group tab

Tags: magento2, product-tab, attribute-group

I want to move '**Discogs Listing**' tab **after the content tab**. I dont know how to do it. drag and drop from attribute set move my tab after the 'Product Reviews' but i want after the 'content' tab

[image]

Any help would be appreciate. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I achieved it using modifier

in your

> app\code\vendor\module\etc\adminhtml\di.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
      <virtualType name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Pool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="modifiers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sap_product" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">vendor\module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Group</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">1000</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
</config>
```

and

> app\code\vendor\module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Group.php

```
<?php
namespace vendor\module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier;

use Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\AbstractModifier;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\ArrayManager;

class Group extends AbstractModifier
{
    public function __construct(ArrayManager $arrayManager)
    {
        $this->arrayManager = $arrayManager;
    }

    public function modifyData(array $data)
    {
        return $data;
    }
    public function modifyMeta(array $meta)
    {
        

        $meta['discogs-listing']['arguments']['data']['config']['sortOrder'] = 20;
        return $meta;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Through this method \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup::addAttributeGroup it is understood that the groups have a sort order. Below is the table that contains them

[image]

Through the repository you can modify its sortOrder:
\Magento\Eav\Model\Attribute\GroupRepository

Cheers